# Fixing Cannot read properties of undefined error in electron app using quasar

Tags: typescript, electron, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am currently working on a small app using the quasar-cli setup with electron.

My electron-preload.ts looks like this:

```
import { contextBridge} from 'electron'
import alasql from 'alasql'

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('Electron', {
  importdata: () => importCsv()
})

export function importCsv () {
  console.log('we get here')
  return alasql.promise('SELECT * FROM CSV("/Users/niki/example_data.csv", {headers:true, seperators:","})')
    .then(function (data) {
      return data
    })
```

In my MainLayout.vue i call it like this:

```
const firstimport = window.electronApi.importdata()
```

I then proceed to use the promise for some further operation which all receive the cannot read properties of undefined error. I also get errors in vscode that .electronApi doesn't exist. Literally the same thing worked in my electron app which wasn't created with quasar-cli so i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Also my window gets created like this, if it's relevant:

```
function createWindow () {
  /**
   * Initial window options
   */
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    icon: path.resolve(__dirname, 'icons/icon.png'), // tray icon
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    useContentSize: true,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      sandbox: false,
      // More info: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-electron-apps/electron-preload-script
      preload: path.resolve(__dirname, process.env.QUASAR_ELECTRON_PRELOAD)
    }
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL(process.env.APP_URL)

  if (process.env.DEBUGGING) {
    // if on DEV or Production with debug enabled
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    // we're on production; no access to devtools pls
    mainWindow.webContents.on('devtools-opened', () => {
      mainWindow?.webContents.closeDevTools()
    })
  }

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = undefined
  })
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: other than these Electron issues, how are you finding using AlaSQL with Vue3 and Quasar? Would you recommend it, or rather be using something else?

Comment: Honestly I haven't tried any other js sql-like libraries and for me it works pretty good so far. I am just importing a rather large csv file and grouping/sorting it, which seems to work fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, After being kept up by this all night and looking at different projects and the old template I used I found my error. First of all i had a typo in electronAPI when calling it. Second of all to make the syntax errors in vscode go away i need the following file:

global.d.ts in my src folder(the renderer folder)

```
import alasql from 'alasql'

/**
 * Should match main/preload.ts for typescript support in renderer
 */
export default interface electronAPI {
  sendMessage: (message: string) => void
  importdata: () => any
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    electronAPI: ElectronAPI,
  }
```

}